# What is the optimal minimum size append one can make into BigQuery while still maintaining high performance for full scans?

Tags: google-bigquery

There are other questions in which the BigQuery team has mentioned we should not do lots of tiny appends.

What is the minimum size of import that one can use while still maintaining high performance?

Comment: There probably isn't a magic number here - it's just that BigQuery works better with fewer big imports. As some of the BigQuery guys mention, you can work around the bias against tiny imports somewhat by using time-based tables (since unions are easy), so maybe make hourly tables or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The performance of BigQuery will start to degrade when the number of fragments gets to be more than a few thousand. We are working on better management of fragmentation, so this shouldn't be as serious of an issue in the future.